# Does anyone know why my pivot table is changing a time value into a date?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

[[image: This is the result I get when I add 'TIME' into the rows section]

[[image: This is a sample of the data I'm working with]

I'm trying to make a pivot table that organizes the 15-minute time increments and shows average pedestrian count for each street recorded. I have been able to do this for smaller sections of the set but for some reason when I try to do the whole thing (about 288,000 rows), it will automatically add 'Years' and 'Quarters' to the table and instead of displaying times, it will just say "Jan, Apr, May, Jun".

It's worth noting that it still recognizes the 'dates' as a time because when I try to format it, it still says 'Time'. Is this just an issue caused by trying to work with too large of a data set? Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Working on Excel for Mac version 16.16.4

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new Excel 2016 time grouping enhancements  are here. You can read about it here - [Time grouping enhancements in Excel 2016](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2015/10/13/time-grouping-enhancements-in-excel-2016/). If automatic grouping is not required, you can remove it by right-clicking on the `time` column in pivot and selecting `Ungroup`.